# Auto-load products using AJAX, go to the correct position of page?

Tags: jquery

I need to auto-load products into a category. The problem with the most auto-load functions is that the visitor is not redirected to the correct position on `Refresh` or `Go Back` buttons of his browser. That's why I decided to try something like that: saving a `location.hash` of the current product page, then retrieve it.

The problem is that it still redirects me to the beginning of the page and I have error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

**category.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pages</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Load Pages
        function LoadPages() {
            if(location.hash) {
                var page = Number(location.hash.split("-")[1]);
            }
            else {
                var page = 1;
            }

            return page;
        }

        // Load Products
        function LoadProducts(type, page) {
            $.get("./ajax.php?action=products&type=" + type + "&page=" + page, function(result) {
                $("#result").append(result);
            });

            location.hash = "page-" + page;
        }

        // Process Start
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var page = LoadPages();

            LoadProducts("start", page);

            $("html,body").animate({
                scrollTop: $("#page-" + page).offset().top
            }, "slow");
        });

        // Process More
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > ($(document).height() - $(window).height() - 100)) {
                var page = LoadPages() + 1;

                LoadProducts("more", page);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
if($_GET) {
    if($_GET['action'] == 'products') {
        if($_GET['type'] == 'start') {
            foreach(range(1, $_GET['page']) as $page) {
                echo '<div style="height: 1000px;" id="page-' . $page . '"><h2>Page ' . $page . '</h2></div>';
            }
        }
        else {
            echo '<div style="height: 1000px;" id="page-' . $_GET['page'] . '"><h2>Page ' . $_GET['page'] . '</h2></div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `LoadProducts` function, the `location.hash = "page-" + page;` statement should appear within the Ajax callback function, else it can be asynchronously executed before the callback function is complete.

Furthermore, it can be helpful to put a slight delay before executing the location.hash to make sure that everything that needs to be processed before is complete. Thus, the `LoadProducts` function could read like the following, which introduces a delay of 2 seconds:

```
// Load Products
        function LoadProducts(type, page) {
            $.get("./ajax.php?action=products&type=" + type + "&page=" + page, function(result) {
                $("#result").append(result);
        setTimeout(function(){ location.hash = "page-" + page;},2000);    
     });
 }
```